# Acessing HTML element with no specific tag on it

Tags: css, html

I need to hide the date in the following code:

```
<div class="post-header">
    March 27, 2018
    <h3 class="title"> Title <h3>
</div>
```

Problem is, I need to keep the title. I tried some stuff like setting `post-header` display to none and the title display to `inline` or `block` 
with !important but it didn't work. I am not too experienced with working the php of wordpress so I am a little stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<h3>` isn't closed.

---

### The Proper Way:

The real way to fix it would be fixing the PHP. In one of your template theme files you'll have

```
<div class="post-header">
    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
    <h3 class="title"> <?php the_title(); ?> <h3>
</div>
```

You'll want to delete the `get_the_date()` line.

If your theme is from an author that updates regularly, and you don't want your changes overwritten by an update - you might want to [explore child-themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), as this is often a use of them.

### The Cheesy CSS Way:

You can't select the text of an element, however you can just layer the `h3` on top of the text - effectively hiding it. Since it's a date, you know the text isn't going to be crazy different from post to post so it's not that hard to cover

```
.post-header {
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.post-header .title {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:-20px;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index:2;
}
```

It's somewhat fragile, and definitely an ugly approach - you'll have to make it a bit more compatible with your theme - but it does solve the problem of the unwanted date.

### The Javascript Way:

Probably the better way to do things (if you can't edit the php theme files) would be with Javascript:

```
const hideMyDates = document.querySelectorAll('.post-header');
for (i = 0; i < hideMyDates.length; i++) {
    hideMyDates[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue = '';
}
```

I used vanilla JS instead of jQuery because it makes small changes like this faster.

If you wanted to throw that in `functions.php`, you'd do:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', function(){
    ?>
    <script>
    //.. the js here
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

---

Regardless of which method you choose, you should contact the theme author and let them know your need of a element on that date text! They might of simply forgotten it and may appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Thank you! I chose to go with the Javascript method until I get access to the php files. Just a small correction in the for loop of it, letter s is missing:  ` hideMyDates[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue = '';` But it works perfectly!